# AIR for iOS - Mouse click getting fired during swipe gesture

Tags: ios, ios5, air, gesture, swipe-gesture

I am developing an AIR for iOS application. I have been facing problems with swipe gesture. I need to apply swipe effect to a movie clip containing child display objects. (like a movie strip with multiple clips).

These child display objects need to be clickable, hence I have added mouse click listener to those. Also I need to scroll the parent movie clip with swipe gesture, so I have added swipe gesture listener to parent movie clip. But the problem I am facing is everytime I am trying to swipe the parent movie clip by swiping my fingers over it, the child display object's (beneath the finger) mouse click event is getting fired.

I need a way to prevent mouse clicks from happening while swiping the parent movie clip.

I am using following setup -

Flash Professional CS6
AIR SDK 3.5

I would really appreciate any help in this regard as I can't seem to get around this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you listening the event, on stage? please provide code.